# AssertionError: expected [Function: proxy] to have a property 'callCount' of 1, but got 0

Tags: reactjs, sinon, enzyme

I have the following React Component for which I want the Button to simulate click and test using Sinon and Enzyme.

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';

class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
  }

  render() {
     return (
       <div className="button">
         <button type="button" className="btn btn-default"
             onClick={this.props.increment}>State</button>
       </div>
     );
  }
}


export default Button;
```

For some reason, my Sinon test fails:

```
describe('on clicking submit', ()=> {
    it('calls submit', () => {
      const onClickSpy = sinon.spy();
      const wrapper = shallow(
        <Button onClick={onClickSpy} />
      );
      wrapper.find('.button').simulate('click');
      expect(onClickSpy).to.have.property('callCount', 1);
    });
  });
```

Error:

```
AssertionError: expected [Function: proxy] to have a property 'callCount' of 1, but got 0
```

What am I missing in my setup?

Please note, my code works fine as when I do npm start -> it runs okay and does what I need it to do.

Comment: Are you sure all props updated before `expect` is called?

Answer (score 1):

Update:

Use `stub` instead of `spy`

The assertion logic is wrong, you need to assert as below

`expect(onClickSpy.callCount).to.equal(1);`